# Как правильно перевести время к 0 по utc?

Tags: python, datetime

Есть, список содержащий переменные даты и времени, нужно их все перевести к 0 по utc. Проблема в том, что у них может быть разный сдвиг. Можно ли перевести их к 0, без заранее прописанного списка с часовыми поясами, как в примере.

**Пример:**

```
#2021-11-03 06:27:27+03:00
UTC_time_format = pytz.timezone('Africa/Abidjan')
new_datetime = dt.astimezone(timezone)
```

А чтобы временная зона автоматически определялась по часову поясу. (В моем примере это +03:00)

Comment: Вы бы хоть формат списка показали. А то я читаю, как "в списке только переменные даты и времени, угадайте их сдвиг" :-)

Comment: @Сергей - они такие же как в примере, только содержаться в списке. Там комментарием указана одна переменная

Comment: Если в переменной "#2021-11-03 06:27:27+03:00" прямо написано "+03:00" , то в чем проблема без всяких библиотек привести к UTC?

Comment: @Сергей, ну как это сделать? Если вы знаете, то напишите ибо у меня не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим есть список дат:

```
time = [2021-11-03 06:27:27+03:00, 2021-11-03 08:27:27+04:00, 2021-11-03 21:47:27+03:30]
```

Его можно привести к 0 по utc следующим образом:

```
UTC_time_format = pytz.timezone('Africa/Abidjan')
for i in time:
    i = i.astimezone()
    i = i.astimezone(timezone)
```

Первый раз astimezone() нужно, чтобы привести все время к времени по нашему часовому поясу, а потом зная его можно привести уже все к 0 по utc